# Any one can tell me whats wrong in my Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to search name with specific ids.

```
select * from members where 1=1 AND MemberID IN('2,8') and Status = '1' AND (FirstName LIKE 'v%') ORDER BY MemberID
```

here is my query. can any one tell me whats wrong and what is the right query to search the name with specific ids.

Thanks

Comment: could you give us the structure of the table members?

Comment: I dont exactly understand why the `1=1` is there for!!!

Comment: there are several things 1=1, memberId IN() with a string parameter, the unnecessary parantesis for the LIKE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You must not use single quotes in IN
>   clause. If your MemberId column is
>   varchar type or character type, you
>   must use MemberID IN('2','8')
>
> but if your MemberID is integer type,
>   you must use: MemberID IN(2,8)

Comment: maybe memberID is a float, IN accepts one value as well. I want to be memberID 6,66 of his application :)

Answer (score 1):

May be the error is in this `MemberID IN('2,8')`. This should be `MemberID IN('2','8')` you have placed single quote in wrong manner.

Also `1=1`? why added this in query?

If you provide error message then it will be more easy to solve it.

Comment: the IN does not requiere a string so it could be IN(2,8) if the memberID is integer

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not bound your numbers with `'` `'`

Answer (score 0):

Your IN clause is probably wrong

- If MemberID is a number it should be:

  ```
     SELECT *
       FROM members
      WHERE 1=1
        AND MemberID IN (2, 8)
        AND Status = '1'
        AND FirstName LIKE 'v%'
   ORDER BY MemberID
  ```
- If MemberId is a string it should be

  ```
     SELECT *
       FROM members
      WHERE 1=1
        AND MemberID IN ('2', '8')
        AND Status = '1'
        AND FirstName LIKE 'v%'
   ORDER BY MemberID
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I think error stands here MemberID IN('2,8')

rather than this you can write MemberID IN('2','8') or MemberID IN(2,8) bcoz it is number so database will accept it.